# Including multiple SQL statements in a single RMarkdown Chunk

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown

I am running SQL statements within my RMarkdown script but it seems that I can only execute 1 statement per chunk. For example running these individually works fine

````
```{sql}
select count(*) from table_1;
```

```{sql}
select count(2) from table_2;
```
````

but if I try combining them into a single chunk I get an error

````
```{sql}
select count(*) from table_1;
select count(*) from table_2;
```
````

ERROR:  cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

Of note I am connecting via DBI::dbConnect to a Redshift DB.

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: @cory I am looking for the same output if something similar were done in R. i.e. nrow(table_1); nrow(table_2) assuming both tables are local.

Comment: Wondering if this error is due to the SQL engine and not RMarkdown itself. Because I think this error is an SQL error. Might just have to have individual SQL chunks per query unless you assign each query to a variable